# Encrypting a django field (not a password)

Tags: python, html, css, django, encryption

I have an ecommerce website made with django and I want to store details of orders. The fields would have id, thing bought, quantity, total price, etc. Right now I only have them stored as plaintext so I want to make it more secure. Hashing isn't an option because I want to be able to read the data. I though about encryption, but is there any other way? If there isn't I have a few questions,
How do I safely encrypt and decrypt the data
Where and how do I store the encryption key
Will there be just 1 master key?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried and [researched](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3929826) so far?

Comment: I found this documentation https://pypi.org/project/cryptography. But I'm not sure if I should just have 1 key for everything or 1key for every row. Another thing is that I'm not sure what's the safest way to store the keys.

Comment: You might have notices that your task actually consist of many sub-tasks to solve. Here on Stack Overflow we can only handle one question per question and it is expected that you show us your best effort in solving it on your own.

Comment: I already know how to encrypt the data. I just don't know what's the safest way of storing the keys.

Comment: Why would you do this? How is this sensitive information?  It's sensible to encrypt passwords, but there's no risk if this kind of information is leaked.

Comment: There are fields like home addresses, full names, email. Shouldn't these data be encrypted? 
Ps. I know I didn't mention these and that was my mistake.

Comment: have you tried out django-cryptography ?

Comment: if it was me first thing i have to do is .1) How to make the key (combining some user's information)? 2) when saving to the database i create and call a function that encrypt the data 3)in my template i create a custom filter for decrypting the data. that is it.with this solution nobody will know the key until they open your code.you do not need to save nothing in the database,i mean the key.

Comment: no i say combine some user's information like by example (his pk and his name) you can make a key and with this the key will be unique.i had a web site in django to secure   my data i use a thing like this and it works very well.

Comment: django-encrypted-fields solves this problem as well

Comment: Aah, so with that way I don't have to store the key at all

Comment: of course you do not have to store the key because you are calling a function and make all your logic there,but make sure you create a good key ,because if not it will be very easy to break your encryption.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: if you need more help on this let me know.

Comment: Will do. But for now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for encrypting the Django model fields
you should creat an EncodedChar class and use it like this:

```
   from utils.char_encoder import EncodedChar
password = EncodedChar(null=False, blank=False, max_length=256, verbose_name=_('Merchant Password'))
```

and my utils.char_encoder file would be:

```
from django.db import models
import base64
import os
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC
from django.conf import settings


class EncodedChar(models.CharField):
    salt = bytes(settings.SECURE_STRING_SALT, 'utf-8')
    kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
                     length=32,
                     salt=salt,
                     iterations=100000,
                     )
    key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(bytes(settings.SECRET_KEY,'utf-8')))
    f = Fernet(key)

    def decrypt_value(self, value):
        value = str(self.f.decrypt(bytes(value, 'cp1252')), encoding='utf-8')
        return value

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        value = str(self.f.encrypt(bytes(value, 'utf-8')), 'cp1252')
        return value
```

as you can see I am using [cryptography](https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/) to encode and decode the CharField and PBKDF2HMAC is the same hashes algorithm used by Django for hashing the password. you can use any other algorithm based on your requirements.